# Working with anonymous class in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm an android beginner, I have some java knowledge, but i'm getting trouble with some android code.

In java we can use anonymous class to override methods of an interface.

I came across the following situation.

```
MyButton.setOnClickListener(New Button.OnClickListener{
    @override
    public void onClick(View view){
      //some code
    }
});
```

I was used to using the anonymous class like so,

```
Interface myInterface = new Interface(){
}
```

I can't just figure out what only New followed by the interface name means,inside a method.

Comment: The method accepts a class that implements the OnClickListener interface.  You would treat the anonymous class exactly the same as you normally would.

Comment: @Jhon answer is correct. And I would also recommend this nice reading about anonymous class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a anonymous class without a variable name

```
MyButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener{
    @override
    public void onClick(View view){
        //some code
    }
});
```

is the same as

```
Button.OnClickListener listener = new Button.OnClickListener{
    @override
    public void onClick(View view){
        //some code
    }
});

MyButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
```